# Producers/consumers with Qt signals/slots

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, producer-consumer

I'm writing a program in which several producers generate some data that should be processed by several consumers. Since the consumption of each piece of data takes around 100ms and the target platform has many processors, it seems natural to me that each producer and each consumer gets its own thread. My question is: Are Qt signals/slots a good way for passing data blocks from producers to consumers? Or do you suggest a better solution (Qt is strongly preferred).

Just in case it's relevant, the producers produce data in bursts of several hundred thousands every hour or so.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. However, take a look at this video, especially starting at 27 min (Cross-thread signal slots): [Qt Developer Days 2011 - Multithreading](http://qt-project.org/videos/watch/advanced-qt-a-deep-dive-3-6-multithreading-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the signal/slot mechanism is appropriate here, because each signal is distributed to *all* connected slots. This means that if you use the signal/slot mechanism as your 'work queue', you don't get any load distribution over the consumers, but rather that all consumers get to do the same (duplicate) work.

A better mechanism would be to use a container as work queue (producers add items to the container, consumers remove them), with a `QMutex` to avoid concurrency problems and one (or two, if you want to impose a maximum size) `QWaitCondition` to block the consumers when there is no work for them.

Comment: Reflecting on my situation, I see that this seems like the best option. I don't seem to find a thread-safe queue class in Qt, like the one Python standard library has, so I'm left with mutexes and wait conditions. It's not terribly difficult but we're a lazy brood, us programmers! If you know of a better option please let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to write a truly generic thread-safe queue, because each project has different requirements on that queue. Just write your own that fits your needs exactly w.r.t. synchronisation and that uses a non-thread-safe container under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to avoid using signals and slots since they act as events so you do not have the control of execution once a signal is emitted. So, I suggest you to use locks or mutexes (QMutex for instance) for mutual exclusion. Simply protect your queues by using lock and unlock methods from QMutex class. I think it will be faster than using signals and slots since if you pass objects it will pass copies of the objects and, in the case you pass pointers, you won't be protecting the objects.

Cheers,